# jUnit Issue - Integration tests for restful web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, junit

I am a C# Developer recently started exploring the Restful web services in Java and I bumped into a weird issue and its not with any functionality in the rest service but with the Integration tests.

The Integration tests are quite simple it hits the Rest URL and it does the checking from the client response received. The tests have no compilation errors and this is a seperate test project and when i try to run the tests through jUnit. or try to run the test file as jUnit test I am getting this error.

```
There was an error while accessing the DNS servers from the resolver: 
There was an error while accessing the search domains from the resolver:
```

When i do a mvn verify / clean install on the project I see that same test is running with no problem at all. All other projects on my machine run successfully on both jUnit and Maven seperately. I am not sure if its the problem with jUnit or anyone has seen a similar problem like this.

As a matter of fact my unit tests for the same web service runs in jUnit successfully and its this one particular bunch of tests which are giving me the afore mentioned error message with jUnit tests on my console.

I look forward to your perspective on this. Thanks and Cheers !

Comment: One possibility is proxy configuration which works fine from maven but not from junit.

Comment: is there a way to manually resolve the proxy configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an eclipse configuration error. Reinstall resolved the issue. Cannot replicate the issue again. I found it very weird though. Seems like none encountered it before.